# How to bring many rows to one row in dataTable

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I am creating page using JSF 2.0 where I am displaying all images that are there.
Code I used is:

```
<h:dataTable id="imageList3" value="#{PersonalInformationDataBean.loadReviewReportDataById()}" var="reviewMyList" width="100%" border="1">
    <h:column>
        <h:graphicImage 
        value="DisplayImage?mainID=reviewReport&amp;id=#{reviewMyList.drawingId}" 
        />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Currently this is displaying one image per row which is right. What I wanted to do is, display **four images in 1 row**. If there are 9 images that I should have output in below format and not 9 rows.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Image 1 + Image 2 + Image 3 + Image 4 +
+ Image 5 + Image 6 + Image 7 + Image 8 +
+ Image 9 +         +         +         +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Please let me know if this is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place four `<h:column>` with single `h:graphicImage` in each or four `h:graphicImage` in one `<h:column>`

well, you can modify your object (reviewMyList) to hold up to 3 inner objects which you will access inside each column like

`reviewMyList.first.drawingId`

`reviewMyList.second.drawingId`

`reviewMyList.third.drawingId` ,

ofcourse you will have to add

`rendered="reviewMyList.first ne null"`

`rendered="reviewMyList.second ne null"`

`rendered="reviewMyList.third ne null"` to your `<h:graphicImage`

Comment: Thanks again for answer Daniel. I will look into it and get back to you

Comment: I have include four h:column, however problem is that data table is behaving like FOR loop. as there are 9 rows in DB, I am getting 9 rows. How can I make these as 3 rows with different id for `id=#{reviewMyList.drawingId}`. For each h:column I have to change id for each graphicImage. hope you got what I meant to say...

Comment: well, you can modify your object (reviewMyList) to hold up to 3 inner objects which you will access inside each column like `reviewMyList.first.drawingId` `reviewMyList.second.drawingId` `reviewMyList.third.drawingId` , ofcourse you will have to add `rendered="reviewMyList.first ne null"` `rendered="reviewMyList.second ne null"` `rendered="reviewMyList.third ne null"` to your `<h:graphicImage `